# ReactJS: fake path issue but I need the correct file path

Tags: reactjs, amazon-s3

I have to upload an image on S3 bucket and I need a file object with proper path. Currently when I upload the image then I get the following in console

```
 C:\fakepath\download (1).jpeg
```

and when it is uploaded on s3 bucket then I am getting 'undefined' as below:

```
https://test-profile-images.s3.amazonaws.com/undefined
```

Basically, I have created a repeater. Below is my code.
how can I fix this?

```
import React, {useState} from "react"

const BrandDetails = (props) => {
  return (
    props.brandDetail !== '' ? 
    props.brandDetail.map((val, idx) => {
      let model = ` model-${idx}`
      return (
        <tr key={val.index}>
          <td>
            <input className="form-control"  defaultValue={val.model} name="model" data-id={idx} id={model} accept="image/x-png,image/jpeg, image/jpg, image/webp" type="file" required/>
          </td>  
        </tr >
      )
    })
    : null
  )
}
export default BrandDetails
```

```
import React, {Fragment, Component} from 'react'
import Breadcrumb from '../../common/breadcrumb'
import Brand from '../brands'
import BrandDetails from './brandRepeater'
import { uploadImage } from '../../common/imageUploader'

class CreateBrand extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.brandObj = new Brand();
        this.state = {
            brandDetail: [{ index: Math.random(), model:"" }],
        }
    }

    onSubmit = (e) => {
        let params = ''

            this.state.brandDetail.map( detail => {
                console.log('image url : ',detail['model'])

                uploadImage(detail['model'])
                .then(res => {
                    console.log('uploaded url', res)
                    let asset = {
                        'src': res.location,
                        'width': 400,
                        'height': 400,
                        'main': true
                    }
                 })
              })
        }

  addNewRow = (e) => {
        this.setState((prevState) => ({
            brandDetail: [...prevState.brandDetail, { index: Math.random(), model:""}],
        }));
    }

    deteteRow = (index) => {
        this.setState({
            brandDetail: this.state.brandDetail.filter((s, sindex) => index !== sindex),
        });
    }

    clickOnDelete(record) {
        this.setState({
            brandDetail: this.state.brandDetail.filter(r => r !== record)
        });
    }

render() {
  return {
    <Fragment>
     <table className="table mt-3">
       <thead>
         <tr>
           <th>Model</th>
         </tr>
       </thead>  
      <tbody>
         <BrandDetails add={this.addNewRow} delete={this.clickOnDelete.bind(this)} brandDetail={brandDetail} flag={flag} /> 
      </tbody>      
   </table>
  </Fragment>
 }
}
}
```